# SQL Database setup issues

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to setup a database for a simple shopping cart app. I have a create.php file that should establish the tables. I'm getting new syntax errors everytime I fix one and I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'conn.php';
$sql = <<<EOS
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
    product_id int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    price decimal(10,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
    description varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
    image_path varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
    name varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
    quantity int(4),
    long_description varchar(700) NOT NULL default '',
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
)
EOS;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or
    die(mysql_error());
    $sql = <<<EOS
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers (
        customer_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        first_name varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
        last_name varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
        suffix varchar(10),
        billing_address varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
        shipping_address varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
        email varchar(255),
        phone int(10) NOT NULL default '0000000000',
        password varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
        PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
    ) 
EOS;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or
    die(mysql_error());
    $sql = <<<EOS
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS address (
        address_id int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        address_line_1 varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
        address_line_2 varchar(50),
        city varchar(40) NOT NULL default '',
        state char(2) NOT NULL default '',
        zip_code int(5) NOT NULL default '00000',
        PRIMARY KEY(address_id)
    )
EOS;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or
    die(mysql_error());
    $sql = <<<EOS
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (
        order_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        customer_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(order_id),
        FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id)
    )
EOS;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or
    die(mysql_error());
    $sql = <<<EOS
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cart_items (
        cart_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        product_id int(4) NOT NULL default '',
        quantity int(5) NOT NULL default '',
        PRIMARY KEY(cart_id),
        FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id)

EOS;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or
    die(mysql_error());
echo "<html><head><h1>Tables created!!</h1></head></html>";

?>
```

This is my latest error: *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6.* Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First figure out _which_ query has the problem. Comment them out and run one at a time, or use `echo` statements after each one so you can quickly find the problem query. You can also copy each query into a MySQL client and test them individually and narrow it down quickly.

Comment: Your last query is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: You can't have `default ''` for integer column types

Comment: I'd assume jszobody is correct with the last query and the fact you should separate it out.  What is the point of using NOT NULL and setting default to `''`?

Comment: Another improvement might be to output table name along with the error in the die method.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. I'm not seeing the missing parenthesis though. ? And I removed any default '' cases I had in there.

Comment: Nevermind on the parenthesis...got it.

Comment: That seemed to fix it. It created all my tables at least. Thank you everyone. I'm sure I'll have many more questions before this assignment is finished.